# Dual booting Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 7 Pro with BitLocker

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, bitlocker

I have an Alienware M11x R2 and I am considering enabling BitLocker. I dual boot this machine and it runs Windows 8.1 Pro as well as Windows 7 Pro. Is it possible to use BitLocker with this setup and will I be able to access files from both installs while I am using the other? I have symbolic links in Windows 8.1 to folder locations on the Windows 7 install that I need to be able to access. Any thoughts or suggestions on this would be appreciated. I've already searched google and bing for this but was unable to find any direction for using bitlocker with windows 7 and windows 8 dual boot post install.

Comment: `Windows 7 Professional` doesn't have the capability to enable FDE with Bitlocker.  So you wouldn't be able to use full disk encryption on the system drive itself.  I have serious doubts, even if you had the correct version of Windows 7 that did support this, full disk encryption would even work on the system drive then.  You can encrypt a non-system disk and both versions of Windows could unlock the drive.

Comment: I have a copy of Windows 7 Ultimate I could upgrade to but you don't think that would work? Would I need to enable BitLocker on both Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 or just one?

Comment: I don't believe it to be possible to use FDR and dual-boot to multiple installions of Windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run a multi-boot system where all operating systems have a system encrypted drive.

Every operating system encrypts it C: drive on its on. So boot in every OS and encrypt only its own C: drive. When you launch OS #1 it will see the other OS's drives as "Bitlocker encrypted volumes" which you can unlock as normal.

However, you specifically mention symbolic links. Hopefully, whatever you have linked together, is not required for booting up. I suspect you have linked certain program (cache) folders which are not required on boot. Secondary drives can be auto-unlocked after you log into your primary operating system. From there on you can access shared files via symbolic links.